# find_each with order and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, rails-postgresql

I need to limit and order batches of records and am using find_each.  I've seen a lot of people asking for this and no really good solution.  If I've missed it, please post a link!

I have 30M records and want to deal with 10M with the highest value in the weight column.

I tried using this method someone wrote: [find_each_with_order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each#698-Will-discard-any-order-option) but can't get it to work.

The code from that site doesn't take order as an option.  Seems strange given that the name is find_each_with_order.  I added it as follows:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
# normal find_each does not use given order but uses id asc
def self.find_each_with_order(options={})
  raise "offset is not yet supported" if options[:offset]
  page = 1
  limit = options[:limit] || 1000
  order = options[:order] || 'id asc'      
  loop do
    offset = (page-1) * limit
    batch = find(:all, options.merge(:limit=>limit, :offset=>offset, :order=>order))
    page += 1
    batch.each{|x| yield x }
    break if batch.size < limit
  end
end
```

and I'm trying to use it as follows:

```
class GetStuff
  def self.grab_em
    file = File.open("1000 things.txt", "w")
    rels = Thing.find_each_with_order({:limit=>100, :order=>"weight desc"})
    binding.pry
    things.each do |t|
      binding.pry
      file.write("#{t.name} #{t.id} #{t.weight}\n" )
      if t.id % 20 == 0
        puts t.id.to_s
      end
    end
    file.close
  end
end
```

BTW I have the data in postgres and am going to grab a subset and move it to neo4j, so I'm tagging with neo4j in case any of you neo4j people know how to do this.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can do something like this:

```
weight = Thing.order(:weight).select(:weight).last(10_000_000).first.weight

Thing.where("weight > ?", weight).find_each do |t|
 ...your code...
end
```